# AWS Lambda/Event Driven Architecture Best Practice

Tags: aws-lambda

I am relatively new the AWS Lambda, I wanted to run my workflow through people who are more experienced. I am generating alerts(15-20), each alert is unique, they talk to another service using a few API calls. I have turned these API calls into Lambda functions which each alert uses respectively. One of the lambdas iterates over each alert and sends the alert name using SNS to another lambda function which turn the alert names into classes which then call the main of the class. I did this to avoid making a lambda function per alert. My question is whether that was a good strategy, or would it be best to create a lambda function per alert? So, instead of sending the alert name using SNS to invoke the second lambda, it would invoke a lambda with the given alert name. The one downside I see to way I've done it is that I am seeing logs of all alerts inside of one lambda function vs creating a lambda function per alert and muddying up the cdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the above it seems like you may have made a good decision keeping it in one Lambda function as having 10/15 lambdas all just generating an alert seems like it can be a bit more complex in terms of management and developer experience when it comes to testing these functions and maintaining code but would segment the logs into different log groups.

Unless the code for generating an alert is dramatically different and cannot be shared following the **DRY** principle then I would recommend a single lambda function to handle your alerting.

Regarding you noisy logs because of alerts, I would recommend looking into structured logging and using [**Log Insights**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html) for queries and building dashboards around your specific alerts and that way you can filter out each alert type almost like you would if your query a database for specific data.

You can find documentation on structured logging here: [**Parsing logs and structured logging**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/parse-logs.html)